# my .htaccess mod_rewrite rule doesn't work properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up a site and using the .htaccess file to rewrite all my URL's so that the .php isn't needed.

> E.G. www.blahblah.com/file

instead of

> www.blahblah.com/file.php

My .htaccess file is currently this:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.co.uk/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.co.uk$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.co.uk/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.co.uk$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.co.uk/match/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.co.uk/match$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.co.uk/match/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.co.uk/match$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

and my site is stored in the directory /match..

Please some one tell me why my links won't work :( its been bugging me for hours!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved sorry everyone, wasting all your times!